# heroku push play 2 failed fetching buildpack

Tags: heroku, playframework-2.0

It used to work. What is the issue?

```
-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Fetching custom buildpack... failed
 !     Heroku push rejected, error fetching custom buildpack

 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:my-heroku.git'
```

Comment: A little more information would be useful....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using a custom buildpack that can't be retrieved.  If you don't need a custom buildpack for your app then just use the standard Scala / Play 2 buildpack:

```
heroku config:add BUILDPACK_URL=https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-scala.git
```

This should be the default for Play 2 apps.